# I'm trying to detect the contours on a red object in an image but I keep getting an error when using the openCv cv.findContour function

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I'm trying to get the contours of a portion of an image but I keep getting an error when I call the cv.findContour image. To find the object in the image I first try to extract the colour of the object, which is red, then I try to find the contours on the detected objects.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


def main():

    image_find_goal = "image.jpg"
    kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    #findGoal(image_find_goal)
    img1 = cv.imread(image_find_goal)
    img = cv.resize(img1,(700,700))
    hsv = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    #range for red color
    lower_r = np.array([160,100,100])
    upper_r = np.array([179,255,255])
    mask = cv.inRange(hsv,lower_r,upper_r)
    res = cv.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask)
    _,thresh = cv.threshold(res,125,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
    dilate =  cv.dilate(thresh,None,iterations=1)

    contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(dilate,cv.RETR_TREE,cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    for cnt in contours:
        epsilon = 0.1*cv.arcLength(cnt,True)
        approx = cv.approxPolyDP(cnt,epsilon,True)
        if len(approx) == 4:
            cv.drawContours(img,cnt,-1,(60,255,255),4)

    cv.imshow('OBSTACLES',img)
    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.destroyWindow(img)
```

The error I get is:

> contours, hierarchy =
> cv.findContours(dilate,cv.RETR_TREE,cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) cv2.error:
> OpenCV(4.4.0)
> /tmp/pip-req-build-sw_3pm_8/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp:195:
> error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats)
> [Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode !=
> CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function
> 'cvStartFindContours_Impl'

Comment: Why are you thresholding after you used cv.inRange() to get a binary mask. Is not the mask finding the red and do you not want the contours from the mask. I suggest you use cv.imshow after each step to make sure each produces what is expected. You can also check the shape and dtype to be sure those are as expected. cv.findContours returns different number of values depending upon your OpenCV version. Check that you are using the correct number of return values.

Comment: Post your input image so we can see what you are trying to do?

Comment: Your structuring element in the dilate is "None". You cannot dilate without a proper structuring element. I do not know if there is a default when you specify "None", since I always use morphologyEx() with a proper structuring element (kernel)

Answer (score 0):

I think this snippet solves your issue. Since you are interested in Contours I would apply the [Canny Edge Detection](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_canny/py_canny.html) before dilating. This move will fix also the CV Type error you are getting

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

image_find_goal = "image.jpg"
#findGoal(image_find_goal)
img1 = cv.imread(image_find_goal)
img = cv.resize(img1,(700,700))
hsv = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

#range for red color
lower_r = np.array([160,100,100])
upper_r = np.array([179,255,255])
mask = cv.inRange(hsv,lower_r,upper_r)
res = cv.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask)
_,thresh = cv.threshold(res,125,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)

# check which are the best canny threshold values for your image
imgCanny = cv.Canny(thresh, 180, 180)
dilate = cv.dilate(imgCanny, None, iterations = 1)
# cv.imshow("dilate", dilate)
# cv.waitKey()

contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(dilate,cv.RETR_TREE,cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for cnt in contours:
    epsilon = 0.1*cv.arcLength(cnt,True)
    approx = cv.approxPolyDP(cnt,epsilon,True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        cv.drawContours(img,cnt,-1,(60,255,255),4)

cv.imshow('OBSTACLES',img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```